# Windows repositioned to macbook screen after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015, OS X El Capitan, 10.11.5) with Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB connected to an external monitor:

Samsung SE790C:

- Resolution: 3440 x 1440 @ 60 Hz
- Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
- Mirror: Off
- Online: Yes
- Rotation: Supported
- Connection Type: DisplayPort
- Television: Yes

Every time my MacBook wakes up from sleep, all my windows are back to the MacBook screen. I have a similar setup at home (same MacBook but with a Dell 26' monitor) and this does **not** happen.

Anything I can do about that? If more info is needed, just let me know! Thanks in advance for any help on that!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after pulling my hair for a few days...

I actually had to tick the "Displays have separate Spaces" option in System Preferences => Mission Control

Does this setting depend on the monitor that is plugged in? I would suppose the answer is yes, otherwise it would not work with my home monitor... To be tested and confirmed!